# Using SQL Joins in MySQL/Connector C++

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, join

I'm using connector c++ to interact with mysql database through c++ and now want to make query to **join two tables in connector c++**.

I know how to join two tables in sql but how to do this in connector c++?

Does connector c++ has class or function to do this job?

I searched a lot in xdevapi documentation but haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment there is no first-class support for `JOIN`s in the X DevAPI, you need to use SQL. Check out [`Session.sql()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-cpp/8.0/classmysqlx_1_1abi2_1_1r0_1_1_session.html#a2e625b5223acd2a3cbc5c02d653a1426).

Disclaimer: I'm the lead dev of the MySQL X DevAPI connector for Node.js.